# Power Bi DAX Avg

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 columns and I am trying to get the average of step counts per id in a power bi measure. Would be great if someone faced a scenario like this and shed some light on it.

[image]

Should be giving me "avg. 9"

Comment: the most basic version would be `AvgSteps = AVERAGE(Table[step count])`, then you use id & this measure in the visual

Comment: The number still comes out wrong this way, @Stachu

Comment: and what number do you expect to see? e.g. what's the average for id 123456, and what should it be for all 4 aggregated?

Comment: @stachu It should be giving me 9 but it is giving me 5

Comment: try `AvgStepsById = AVERAGEX(VALUES(Table[id]),CALCULATE(MAX(Table[step count])))` and remove Table[step count] from the visual

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Trying AvgStepsById = AVERAGEX(VALUES(Table[id]),CALCULATE(MAX(Table[step count]))) worked! Thank you Stachu

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.